# How can I verify my bitcoin transaction independently?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am newbie in cryptocurrencies, and sorry if my question is really stupid.

For example, I sent to some wallet btc, can I don't wait that someone will verify my transaction ,and I'll verify it by oneself?

Comment: Transactions are verified by miners (or more accurate by the code that runs on those machines). The idea is to keep the data valid by having at least x miners confirm it is valid. Without that mechanism, invalid data could be added to the chain.

So, no, you can not validate your own transaction. It would be like you send a transfer request to your bank, and tell the employee they don't have to check anything, coz you already did.

Comment: I understand, but can I be that miner, but for myself?For example, can I use some software for mining, and verify my transaction here?If I have hash of transaction for example.

Comment: You are missing the concept of blockchain, what is in a block and why and how validation  is done. When you are a miner, it could happen you are the one mining a block that contains one or more of your own transactions. But you can't decide to validate your own transactions.

What would happen if you create a transfer from my account to yours and validate that yourself? Or when you transfer more BTC to another account than you have in your own account, and you validate that?

Comment: I understood, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As RST pointed out in the comment, Transactions are verified by miners, they do so by receiving a part of the transaction as a reward, the higher this amount, the faster your block will get confirmed because more people will want to mine it to get this reward, as soon as this happens, the transaction will be verified and you can check it by inserting the transaction ID in any mainstream [blockchain explorer](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer)

Answer (score -1):

The other answer given here is not entirely correct nor does it actually answer the question that was asked, so I am going to do my best to correctly answer this question as well as supply supplemental information relating to why the other answer was provided.

First of all, to answer the how can you. I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the node configuration. Specifically I recommend reading https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#blocks-only-mode. This is a link to the block only mode configuration settings which allow you to whitelist only peers you approve, thus you can set it up so your nodes only see your own transactions. This means you would only be approving your own transactions. SO for example in theory you could approve transactions such as low fee transactions during a high fee peek time when other nodes may reject transaction for not meeting minimum requirements.

However, and this is where things get tricky, mining pools are not going to allow setups that are accepting low fee transactions. This means you are only going to be able to do this as a solo miner. As a solo miner unless you have tens of millions of US dollars sitting around to creating your own mining farms, you are almost assuredly never going to actually mine a block. This is because there are countless miners that compete to solve an equation and the first to solve it wins the rewards. If you are not the person to solve it, and your fee's are too low its not getting accepted into the block. So you would have to try and try again... thus practically, what it is possible by definition, is a statistical improbability mathematically and even if you achieved it one time, it would be unlikely to ever happen twice.

Also understand there is what's called "Exclusive mining" and "Conformations as a service". Check out this great pdf posting about what exclusive mining is https://www.blockchainresearchlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Exclusive_Mining_of_Blockchain_Transactions_BRL_Working_Paper_No_13.pdf

So this should answer both "how can I" and why "you aren't going to be able to".

I hope this helps both you ans future readers trying to understand bitcoin and blockchain more.